# get total reservations per user

Tags: powerbi, dax

i need some help i need a table that contains the name of the CompanyUser and amount of reservations each CompanyUser user has. but the problem is that i can't join 4 tables each table is connected with a different key.

in sql i can do it but in power bi i tried NATURALLEFTOUTERJOIN and NATURALRIGHTINNERJOIN but the problem is that when you did a join and want to join an other table to the created table from before it says can't find an connection.

can somebody help me out.

here is the table
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCwWX.png)

this is the example result
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KNvX.png)

Comment: You have 2 Company User table?

Comment: no only on the other table is companyusertreatement @OzanSen

Comment: Why do you have inactive relationships? This looks like a simple `COUNTROWS` of `Reservation` where the evaluation context is the primary row content of `CompanyUser`, but your relationships are not active, so will not propagate filters without use of `USERELATIONSHIP` invoked within `CALCULATE`.

Comment: @Marcus can you explain with an example ? its because every user is linked to a company and each company has many companyuserthreatmensts. and for each  companyuserthreatmensts there is a reservation and i need to know how many reservation eche employee/user has

Comment: You are not answering my question at all. I suggest you read what I wrote again, and find out what an inactive relationship is, and why that is a likely problem in your data model.

Comment: @WannesLimbourg You need to make the relationships active If you want a filter in your Company User table to reach reservation table. Marcus is right.

Comment: I did the research of Active USERELATIONSHIP but i don't understand how to fix it. cause you can only us it via Calculate. @OzanSen. I did try this to get to calculation of Reservation for each user but don't know how to get further.

CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS('turnup Reservation'),
    USERELATIONSHIP(users[Id],'turnup CompanyUser'[UserId]),
    USERELATIONSHIP('turnup CompanyUserTreatment'[CompanyUserId],'turnup CompanyUser'[Id]),
    USERELATIONSHIP('turnup CompanyUserTreatment'[Id],'turnup Reservation'[CompanyUserTreatmentId]),
    ADDCOLUMNS( users, "name", RELATED(users[Name])
))

Comment: i have updated the image cause it reservation en companyuser arn't making direct connection @Marcus

Comment: Thanks @WannesLimbourg. I understand your logic. Is it possible to share some data ? It is not supposed to be your real data. I am sure that people will then react to your post faster.

Comment: @OzanSen can we speak maybe on an other platform in private?